# Turtle stopped eating food post accident

Tags: feeding, turtles

My turtle fell off from the 5th floor. She was bleeding from her mouth for two days but then stopped. I saw her opening her mouth and I could not see any injured mark. The local vet she is fine, the bleeding was due to shock and that for 3-4 days she won't eat anything. I am a little worried. She is swimming and excreting as well. Kindly, let me know if anyone else has the same experience.

Comment: the answers in the original post is very good and they cover this fully,please read them and post comments if something needs to be made clearer.